# java: How do I stop a thread that waits for long periods

Tags: java, multithreading

i hava a program connect to server through **xot (x25 over tcp/ip)** protocol.

i have a thread to connect, send recv data with server using xot library.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{

    public MyThread() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        // init sock
        ...

        // connect to server
        sock.connect("server_address", timeout);

        System.out.println("send data ..");
        sock.send(data);

        System.out.println("send data ok, recv data ..");

        Data data = sock.recv();
        System.out.println("recv data ok");
    }

}
```

My lib i use can handle connect timeout, but there is no method like setSoTimeout() to handle timeout when send & recv data.

So, i dont know how to stop mythread right-way when send & recv method run for a long time.

anyone could suggest me some solution.

thanks

Quan

Answer (score 1):

```
MyThread myt = new MyThread();
myt.start();
... later on ...
myt.interrupt();
```

Note that `interrupt()` isn't completely fool-proof (read the docs), but the odds are good that it will help in your situation.  You may additionally need to modify your own code (within `MyThread`) to check the interrupted status using `interrupted` or `isInterrupted`

Comment: Note that you need a second Thread (or Timer) to fire the interrupt as the thread cannot interrupt itself.

Comment: oh, how to add code to check interrupt status when mythread suspend at recv method to wait resp from server (no print "recv data ok")

Comment: I don't think interrupt() works for his custom socket library, unless it is implemented by nio. If not, recv already blocks and there's no ways of periodically checking interrupt status.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't catch whether the send/receive you're blocking/waiting on is a "normal" TCP/IP socket; but if so, it's fairly easy to abort an I/O operation from the outside by simply closing the socket. This is not widely known but is AFAIK perfectly legal, and it works like a charm.

The I/O operation yields an `IOException`, of course, but that's easy enough to catch and then you can exit your Thread's `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a volatile flag and a while loop that counts down until the timeout is exhausted or a connection happens.

Comment: how to add a while loop while my thread suspend at recv method to wait data from server ?